# Kendo editor required kendo javascript for angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I have a concise question:
Which Kendo libraries are required for the Kendo editor in AngularJS? 
On the tutorial site (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/angular) it states "kendo.all.min.js"is required, although I would not choose this option as it is quite resource wasting.
Help is appreaciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what exacly you need for editor components:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/scripts-editors
and frameworsks: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/scripts-frameworks

So based on that for editor in angular there is required:

- jquery.js
- kendo.core.js
- kendo.data.js
- kendo.popup.js
- kendo.list.js
- kendo.dropdownlist.js
- kendo.angular.js

Optional, for mobile scroller feature:

- kendo.fx.js
- kendo.userevents.js
- kendo.draganddrop.js
- kendo.mobile.scroller.js

And optional for VirtualList feature:

- kendo.virtuallist.js